# How to download and display text and png files in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, angular-ui

I have text and image files stored on a server that I need to download and present in an html web page.  I'm using AngularJS to render the page.  If I acquire the files using the code below, then I get an http 200 status response, but the file is not in the body or any where else in the response.  If i enter the exact same URI in my FireFox browser, I get the standard prompt to save the file locally, so I know the uri works.

How do I acquire it in AngularJS?  When I get it, how do I display them?

```
app.controller('MainController', function($scope, dataService) {
    $scope.data = null;
    dataService.getData().then(function(dataResponse) {
        $scope.data = dataResponse;
    });
});

app.service('downloadService', function($http) {
    delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    this.getData = function() {
        console.log("getting data");
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://someAddress.com/pathtofile.txt?securitykey=fakeKey',
            params: '',
            headers: {}
        });
    }
});
```

-- Update --

As per the comment below, I updated the code to the following, but I only see an icon place holder for the image, not the image itself.

```
var app = angular.module('MyTutorialApp',[]);

app.controller("MainController", function($scope){
    $scope.path_to_image = "https://someAddress.com/pathtofile.png?securitykey=fakeKey"
});

<div id='content' ng-app='MyTutorialApp' ng-controller="MainController">
    <img ng-src="path_to_image">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For image files no need to write http handler

You can display image -

controller.js

```
$scope.path_to_image = "https://someAddress.com/pathtofile.png"
```

html

```
<img ng-src="path_to_image">
```

Comment: Thanks Onsey.  The request to get the files is through an Atmos ObjectStore, so I need to include the security keys as http parameters.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Answer is still valid, why you need to make http handler, 

If I am not wrong, it its have valid key then it will get image right? If yes the only change,
$scope.path_to_image = "https://someAddress.com/pathtofile.png?securitykey=fakeKey"

Comment: I tried your recommendation but I only see an icon image placeholder instead of the actual image.  I've updated the original question with what I wrote based on your recommendation.

Comment: I figured out the problem.  You need the {{}} brackets around the scoped variable.  Onsy, if you update your proposed solution to read "<img ng-src="{{path_to_image}}">", I will accept it.